# Different C++ fork() behavior between CentOS 7.5 & RockyLinux 8.4, Ubunu 20.04

Tags: c++, c, fork

I'm working with some legacy code. It works fine on a CentOS 7 system. The args array gets hosed on both a Rocky 8.4 and Ubuntu 20.04 system. I've simplified the problem and added print statements. The execv() was launching another program. The args going into the execv get messed up. Without the fork, the code works as expected. Baffled.

I have two simple test programs, one of which does nothing.

test9.cpp

```
int main(){}
```

and test10.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> stringArgs;
   std::string a{"./test9.x"};
   std::string b{"test10.cpp"};
   stringArgs.push_back(a);
   stringArgs.push_back(b);
        char* args[stringArgs.size()+1];
   if(fork() == 0){
        for(uint8_t i = 0; i < stringArgs.size(); i++) {
            std::string tmp(stringArgs[i]);
            args[i] = const_cast<char*>(tmp.c_str());
        std::cout << "\n\t"<<args[i]<<"'\n\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n\t"<<args[0]<<"'\n\n";
        std::cout << "\n\t"<<args[1]<<"'\n\n";
        // last argument has to be NULL
        args[stringArgs.size()] = NULL;
    
        execv(args[0],&args[0]);
        std::cout << "\n\tERROR: Could not run '"<<args[0]<<"'\n\n";
   }
   else
    std::cout<<"parent\n";
}
```

`g++ -o test9.x test9.cpp; g++ -o test10.x test10.cpp`

On the CentOS 7 I get:

```
$ ./test10.x

    ./test9.x


    test10.cpp


    ./test9.x


    test10.cpp

    parent
```

And on both Rocky Linux 8.4 and Ubuntu 20.04 I get this. Notice the test9.x gets replaced by test10.cpp after the for loop.

```
./test10.x
parent

    ./test9.x


    test10.cpp


    test10.cpp


    test10.cpp


    ERROR: Could not run test10.cpp
```

Comment: Per pm100 below -- you're using variables on the stack in an unsafe fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THis loop

```
   for(uint8_t i = 0; i < stringArgs.size(); i++) {
        std::string tmp(stringArgs[i]);
        args[i] = const_cast<char*>(tmp.c_str());
        std::cout << "\n\t"<<args[i]<<"'\n\n";
    }
```

is creating an array of pointers to a temporary on the stack, or some internal implementation defined part of std::string

do this instead

```
   for(uint8_t i = 0; i < stringArgs.size(); i++) {
        args[i] = strdup(stringArgs[i]);
        std::cout << "\n\t"<<args[i]<<"'\n\n";
    }
```

Comment: My guess is that centos7 did not have the small string optimization so `std::string tmp(stringArgs[i]);` puts the string data on the heap and luckily the memory doesn't get reused. Centos8 / Ubuntu do have the small string optimization so the string data is put into the string object on the stack itself and gets overwritten in each loop. `args[i]` then all point to the same stack address and result in the last argument (test10.cpp).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow - either way it was UB given that code uses 'args' after exit from that loop, so even the last string is gone

Comment: Sure. Just explaining why it sort of worked for this narrow example. Sometimes UB still does what you wanted (for a time).